# How to resolve properly transitive dependencies of Tika in Fuse (camel) bundle?

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-tika, jbossfuse, transitive-dependency

I'm trying to implement Tika functionality in a Fuse (6.3) project. In the last current version 1.16 Tika offers Osgi bundle with parsers. I can't achieve the proper  osgi way to include Tika in my project. Any hint how can I have to create the dependency configuration and use the osgi bundle?

Comment: Are you using Camel Tika Component?

Answer (score 0):

Camel-Tika component is not included in JBoss Fuse 6.3. The Tika 1.16 version is in the camel-tika component, included in camel 2.20.0-SNAPSHOT.